# In Google Slides' Presenter View is there a way to permanently turn off the floating toolbar?

Tags: google-slides

I have need for the virtual laser pointer in Google Slides' Presenter View (I require a pointer graphic that originates from within the presentation window so that it will register in an OBS recording).

However, when the pointer moves into the lower 1/3 of the Slides screen, the floating toolbar reappears, which I find distracting (in my application, it appears behind a disembodied torso that's been green-screened into my OBS recording). I have reasons not to use Powerpoint (on a Mac, in PPT present-in-a-window mode, the virtual laser pointer cannot be toggled with a keystroke as it can in Slides).

I have not been able to find a setting that would leave the floating toolbar permanently invisible. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. If this setting is not available, I will file a feature request

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a built-in setting, so I just wrote this JavaScript to do it:

```js
setInterval(() => {
    const iframe = document.querySelector('.punch-present-iframe');
    if (!iframe) return;
    const innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument ? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;

    const nav = innerDoc.querySelector('.punch-viewer-nav');
    if (nav) nav.style.display = 'none';
}, 1000);
```

Some notes:

- Google changes their CSS class names every once in a while. To find the up-to-date classes, right-click the presentation bar and locate both its iframe ancestor and whichever element will hide the whole bar at the time.
- This is in a `setInterval` so that you can exit and re-enter the presentation and still have it remove the bar.
- Once the bar is gone, the only way I could find to enable the laser pointer is by pressing "L" on the keyboard (i.e. I couldn't figure out how to automate this).